# Size differences in Height/Width between parent ContentView and Display Sizes

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I put the Height/Width of one of my Custom Controls in my Watch-Window and see a huge difference between the sizes of its parent ContentView and the Display Information:

[image]

What is the explanation for the differences? The ContentView is not really smaller or something like that. Should I take these numbers differently or calculate them differently when using them for Size calculations?

Answer (score 1):

First, you could take a look at [Device display information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/display?tabs=macios) and [DisplayInfo.Density Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.devices.displayinfo.density?view=net-maui-7.0)

Okay, suppose you are using iphone13 which resolution is 2532 X 1170 (physical pixels). You could try to figure out this value:

```
DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density
```

And the value for iPhone13 is 3.0. It is also called scale factor. It means one scaled pixel can represent three physical pixels. Although the ContentView Height is 664 (scaled pixels), but actually the physical pixels for it is 664 X 3.0 = 1992.

Many documents talk about this on the Internet.

[Apple's document about scale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617836-scale?language=objc)

Hope it helps!